# Prove that $PA^2+PB^2+PC^2+PH^2=4R^2.$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, circles

A $\Delta ABC$ has orthocentre $H,$ nine-point centre $N$ and circumradius $R.$ For any point $P$ on its nine-point circle, prove that $$PA^2+PB^2+PC^2+PH^2=4R^2.$$

I can prove that $NA^2+NB^2+NC^2+NH^2=3R^2.$ But don’t know how to proceed further. How does the nine-point circle come into play? Any kind of help/suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24PA%5E2%2BPB%5E2%2BPC%5E2%2BPH%5E2%3D4R%5E2%24&p=1 might help. Although I hadn't check.

Answer (score 1):

Place the points $A,B$ and $C$ across the unit circle on the Argand plane with the coordinates $a,b$ and $c.$ Then $$|a|=|b|=|c|=R=1$$
$$H:h=a+b+c$$
$$N:n=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$$
Let $P = p.$ Since $P$ lies on the nine-point circle of $\Delta ABC,$ we have
\begin{align*}
& |p-n|=\frac{R}{2} \\
\implies & \left|p-\frac{a+b+c}{2}\right|=\frac{R}{2} \\
\implies & |2p-a-b-c|=R \\
\implies & (2p-a-b-c)\cdot (2p-a-b-c) = R^2 \\
\implies & 4p\cdot p + a \cdot a + b \cdot b + c \cdot c - 4p \cdot (a+b+c) +2(b \cdot c +c \cdot a + a \cdot b) = R^2 \\ 
\implies & 4p\cdot p + 3R^2 - 4p \cdot (a+b+c) +2(b \cdot c +c \cdot a + a \cdot b) = R^2 \;\;\; [\text{Using}\; |a|=|b|=|c|=R] \\
\implies & 4p\cdot p - 4p \cdot (a+b+c) +2(b \cdot c +c \cdot a + a \cdot b) = -2R^2 \;\;\; (1) 
\end{align*}
Therefore
\begin{align*}
& PA^2+PB^2+PC^2+PH^2 \\
&= (p-a)\cdot (p-a) + (p-b)\cdot (p-b) + (p-c)\cdot (p-c) + (p-h)\cdot (p-h) \\
&= 4p\cdot p + a \cdot a + b \cdot b + c \cdot c + h \cdot h - 2p \cdot(a+b+c+h) \\
&= 4p \cdot p -4p \cdot(a+b+c) +2(a \cdot a + b \cdot b + c \cdot c) + 2(b \cdot c+ c \cdot a + a \cdot b) \;\;\; [\because h = a+b+c] \\
&= 6R^2 + \{4p \cdot p -4p \cdot(a+b+c) + 2(b \cdot c+ c \cdot a + a \cdot b)\} \;\;\; [\text{Using}\; |a|=|b|=|c|=R] \\
&= 6R^2-2R^2 \;\;\; [\text{Using}\; (1)] \\
&= \boxed{4R^2}
\end{align*}
$QED.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $G $ be the centroid of the triangle. Then
$$
\vec{NA}+\vec{NB}+\vec{NC}=3\vec{NG}+\underbrace{\vec{GA}+\vec{GB}+\vec{GC}}_{=0}=-\vec{NH}\\
\implies \vec{NA}+\vec{NB}+\vec{NC}+\vec{NH}=0.
$$
Using this and already proven result
$$
NA^2+NB^2+NC^2+NH^2=3R^2
$$
the claim follows from the law of cosines.

> $$PA^2=NA^2+ R\cdot NA\cos (\angle PNA)+\frac14R^2,$$ the term in the middle being the multiplied by $R$ projection of $\vec{NA}$ on the line $NP$, and similarly for $PB^2$, $PC^2$ and $PH^2$.